# Duplicate name values of multiple closures in the label:[abilities] array

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I'm creating a test Lite Wearable app using Huawei's DevEco IDE.
I created an empty project and added a new page named "LaunchAbility", but when I try to build the project, I receive the error:

> ConfigJsonError: CONFIG_STATUS_ERROR
>
> > Cause: Duplicate name values of multiple closures in the label:[abilities] array.
> > Solution: Ensure that each of the name values is unique across closures in the abilities array.
> > File: C:\Users\olilopez\DevEcoStudioProjects\Test_App_2_2_0_FA_JS_AllDevices\entry\src\main\config.json:29

I've been trying to find out what the problem is but I cannot spot anything wrong in my config.json file, I can't see any "label" or "name" attributes or any other attribute that might contain duplicate values.

Here's what my config.json looks like, if anyone could help me point out where the problem might be, I'll appreciate it:

```
{
  "app": {
    "bundleName": "com.example.test_app_2_2_0_fa_js_alldevices",
    "vendor": "example",
    "version": {
      "code": 1000000,
      "name": "1.0.0"
    }
  },
  "deviceConfig": {
  },
  "module": {
    "package": "com.example.test_app_2_2_0_fa_js_alldevices",
    "name": ".MyApplication",
    "mainAbility": "com.example.test_app_2_2_0_fa_js_alldevices.MainAbility",
    "deviceType": [
      "phone",
      "tablet",
      "tv",
      "wearable",
      "liteWearable"
    ],
    "distro": {
      "deliveryWithInstall": true,
      "moduleName": "entry",
      "moduleType": "entry",
      "installationFree": false
    },
    "abilities": [
      {
        "skills": [
          {
            "entities": [
              "entity.system.home"
            ],
            "actions": [
              "action.system.home"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "name": "com.example.test_app_2_2_0_fa_js_alldevices.MainAbility",
        "icon": "$media:icon",
        "description": "$string:mainability_description",
        "label": "$string:entry_MainAbility",
        "type": "page",
        "visible": true,
        "launchType": "standard"
      },
      {
        "skills": [
          {
            "entities": [
              "entity.system.home"
            ],
            "actions": [
              "action.system.home"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "name": "com.example.test_app_2_2_0_fa_js_alldevices.LaunchAbility",
        "description": "$string:launchability_description",
        "icon": "$media:icon2",
        "label": "$string:entry_LaunchAbility",
        "launchType": "standard",
        "orientation": "unspecified",
        "visible": true,
        "type": "page"
      }
    ],
    "js": [
      {
        "pages": [
          "pages/index/index"
        ],
        "name": "default",
        "window": {
          "designWidth": 720,
          "autoDesignWidth": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```